# What would the sun look like from aphelion of The Goblin's orbit?

Tags: the-sun, dwarf-planets

I was amazed to find out about the discovery of The Goblin [2015 TG387](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_TG387) with an orbital period of more than 32 thousand years and a aphelion of more than 1955 AU! That is an astonishing distance. What would the sun look like from aphelion on The Goblin? Could a naked eye observer distinguish it from the rest of the sky?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, easily.

1955 AU is a long way, but it is only 0.03 of a light year. The sun would still be less than 1/100 of the distance to the next star.

The brightness of the sun would be much less: about 4000000 times less bright, but that is about 16 magnitudes. The sun from Earth is -27 magnitude, so the sun would appear as a magnitude -10 star. It would be much brighter than any other star, and would easily outshine Venus as seen from Earth. In fact it would be 100 times brighter than Venus. It would be as bright as a half-moon (strong enough to cast shadows, but not to read by)